# Как отменить масштабируемость графических объектов в Asctionscript3?

Tags: actionscript-3

Использую класс наследуемый от Spite как хранилище для графических объектов списка отображения, внутри которого есть несколько дочерних элементов с типом данных Shape, они образуют элемент интерфейса. Нужно что бы при масштабировании окна приложения-этот элемент был статичен. Как этого можно добиться? В документации Adobe не увидел ответа

Comment: Это, наверное, для Flex задачка, а не для чистого флеша.

Comment: @Sergey Snegirev Flex, это ж обычная надстройка над нативным AS, со своими контролами, если там такой функционал имеется, значит его можно и в своем коде применить...

Comment: Да, действительно. Нашел решение на английском и описал его для вас :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот прекрасная статья о том, [как создать гибкий интерфейс на AS3](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3fluidresize/):
[image: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3fluidresize/fluid-flash.gif]

Вкратце, требуется запретить масштабирование всего клипа, чтобы растягивание окна увеличивало размер сцены, а не ее масштаб:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

Далее нужно ловить событие `Event.RESIZE`, брать новый размер сцены и "прибивать" нужные элементы интерфейса в новые координаты: растягивать до новой ширины/высоты сцены или передвигать в сколько-то там пикселей от "нового" края.

Comment: Замечательно, то, что нужно. Надо было мне залезть в класс Stage и хорошенько разобраться в нем... он же у нас самый основной на вершине стека для всего списка отображения и там есть события связанные с масштабированием...)спасибо

Comment: Если этот ответ работает, можно ответить его как правильный зеленой галочкой (вот тут - http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)